# Custom router in Blazor with .NET 8

Tags: .net, blazor

I'm trying to upgrade Chris Sainty Blazor router to .NET 8.

https://chrissainty.com/routing/

While uprading all stuff to interactive server from the template (new program.cs, new router, new App.razor) I am facing a 404 error while running the project.

Does anybody know how can I make it work ?

I have a large .NET 7 project that I want to upgrade to .NET 8 but I got stuck with that problem !

Many thanks,

Raphaël

I ended up with this:

```
@page "/{*pageRoute:nonfile}"
@inject WebSiteService webSiteService
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<CascadingValue Value="pageRoute">
    @DynamicComponent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string pageRoute { get; set; }
    private RenderFragment DynamicComponent { get; set; }
    List<RouteVM> routes { get; set; }
    string tmpUrl {get;set;} 
    bool isFound { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        routes = await webSiteService.getRoutes();
    }
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {                
        var route = routes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.page == "/" + pageRoute);            
        
         DynamicComponent = builder =>
        {
            builder.OpenComponent(0, Type.GetType($"MyApp.Components.Pages.{(route!=null ? route.componentName : "NotFound")}"));
            builder.CloseComponent();

        };                        
        
      }      
    }       
}
```

Comment: `Router` has changed a little since Chris's article.  Several of us wrote customized routers in the early days to solve early problems [most of which have gone away or been solved].  It might help if you explained what problem you needed a custom router to solve?

Comment: Hello MrC, thanks for your reply ! What I need to solve is I need to route landing page urls which don't have a specific pattern eg. https://www.jimprimeenfrance.fr/impression-flyer-en-ligne should redirect to landing page, instead this url https://www.jimprimeenfrance.fr/impression-flyer-pas-cher redirects to a product page...

Comment: Apologies but I don't understand your pattern.  I assume you have a current working version of a custom router.  If you ran a normal router what specific url would route incorrectly and to where?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem ;-(

Comment: In fact I have some pages that have to redirect to a specific page (e.g: /Product) and other pages to /LandingPage. The problem is those pages doesn’t have a specific pattern, and are specified in a database. For example the page /impression-flyer-pas-cher redirects (as rewrited) to Product/impression-flyer-pas-cher while /impression-flyer redirects to /LandingPage/impression-flyer.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn’t find a solution

Comment: You could perhaps consider writing a middleware catching the raw url and doing a redirect  to the desired landing page if necessary.

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks for your update but Blazor Server does not support Url Rewriting Middleware with app.Use() it shows a 404 page instead…

Comment: I have opened a case on GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53135